# Form to manage users with multiple submit (change, delete)

Tags: html, forms, php-5.3

I am trying to build a web page for an admin to manage users.

Specifically I am trying to build multiple forms that will make changes to users, delete them, send message etc.

Bottom line is that I want to be able to use form( or many forms) for multiple purposes( sometimes to query user and delete her/him, sometimes to change their information).

Here is sample of the code that roughly show what I want( I am showing just one row of the whole page):

```
<tr><form method="POST" action="????">
<td><input type="text" name="user" value="USER"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="user" value="EMAIL"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="user" value="PRIVILAGES"></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="delete"></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="change"></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="message"></td>
</form></tr>
```

Again this is just a concept fact is I have no idea what is the most efficient way of doing this, so I am open to completely changing this.

Or should I have some script on backed figure out what to do?(delete, change, message?)

Answer (score 0):

First include a hidden field to pass back record id, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" values="123" />
```

Then in PHP use the following to decide what to do with submitted information.

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
if(isset($_POST["delete"])){
    //delete by $id;
}
else if(isset($_POST["change"])){
    //change by $id;
}
else if(isset($_POST["message"])){
    //message by $id;
}
```

Comment: So let me get this straight, when i press submit with name 'delete' only the delete button POST its value the other two wont?

Comment: All the rest of the form values are posted back. But the IF/ELSE condition tells you which one of the three buttons were pressed.